# How to enable the image-dired exif functions?

Tags: image-dired

Apparently image-dired provides [Functions to write and extract Exif comments using ExifTool](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ImageDired) **but** I can't find any of those functions using e.g. `M-x` except `image-dired-copy-with-exif-file-name`.

In particular I want to display the tag value `Description` from the selected thumbnail in the minibuffer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because everything else is *not* a command, so you can't invoke it with `M-x`. Try `M-: (image-dired-get-exif-data <FILE> <TAG>)`.

Note by the way that Emacs 29.1 has obsoleted this mechanism. `C-h f image-dired-get-exif-data` says:

```
image-dired-get-exif-data is a native-compiled Lisp function in
‘image-dired.el’.

This function is obsolete since 29.1; use ‘exif-parse-file’ and
‘exif-field’ instead.

(image-dired-get-exif-data FILE TAG-NAME)

From FILE, return EXIF tag TAG-NAME.

  Probably introduced at or before Emacs version 29.1.
```